# Display Custom Post Type Metabox Data

Tags: wordpress, metadata, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I'm having a problem displaying metabox data in a page template wp_query. I get this error:

Notice: Array to string conversion

Here is my code:

```
  <?php

  // WP_Query arguments
  $args = array (
      'post_type'              => array( 'portfolio' ),
      'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true,
      'posts_per_page'  => '10',

  );

  // The Query
  $portfolio_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  // The Loop
  if ( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ) {
          $portfolio_query->the_post();

    echo '<div id="portfolio">';
    echo '<div class="featured_img">';      
    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . " " . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="portfolio">';
    echo the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );
    echo '<p>' . the_excerpt() . '</p>';
    echo '<p>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID($post->id , 'project_metabox', false) ) . '</p>'; 
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

      }
  } else {
      echo "<h1>There are no portfolio pieces to view.</h1>";
  }

  // Restore original Post Data
  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I've tried everything. This is just the latest version of my attempts. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Alright, so I found out the metadata isn't saving. I'm not exactly sure why, but I tried fixing it, and it's not working. My fixes made it worse. Here is my code: 
`
    public function save_metabox( $post_id, $post ) {

```
    // Check if it's not an autosave.
    if ( wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) )
        return;

    // Sanitize user input.
    $project_new_web_design = isset( $_POST[ 'project_web_design' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
    $project_new_web_development = isset( $_POST[ 'project_web_development' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
    $project_new_digital_art = isset( $_POST[ 'project_digital_art' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';
    $project_new_graphic_design = isset( $_POST[ 'project_graphic_design' ] ) ? 'checked' : '';


    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'project_web_design ', $project_new_web_design  );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'project_web_development ', $project_new_web_development  );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'project_digital_art ', $project_new_digital_art  );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'project_graphic_design ', $project_new_graphic_design  );

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue you're having is on this line:

```
echo '<p>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID($post->id , 'project_metabox', false) ) . '</p>';
```

You seem to have mixed `get_the_ID` and `$post->ID` together. You're also attempting to echo an array.

The third parameter of `get_post_meta` will determine whether the value returned is a string or an array. Use `true` to return a single value.

Change it to:

```
echo '<p>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'project_metabox', true ) . '</p>';
```

On a minor note you're trying to echo functions like `the_excerpt()`. You'll typically find that functions starting `the_` instead of `get_the_` will output directly instead of returning a value. Furthermore `the_excerpt()` will automatically add paragraph tags.

Replace this:

```
echo '<p>' . the_excerpt() . '</p>';
```

With this:

```
the_excerpt();
```